# Elm Pattern matching on Generic Data Structure

Tags: generics, pattern-matching, elm

Given this code:

```
type Msg 
    = NoOp
    | UpdateField ReqRes


type ReqRes a
    = Request a
    | Response (Result Http.Error Bool)


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateField reqres ->
            case reqres of
                Request a ->
                    -- Do stuff
                Response result ->
                    -- Do stuff
        _ -> 
            -- Do stuff
```

So as you can See I have a Msg named UpdateField, that takes the UnionType ReqRes. So far so good. But the Union Type has a Generic Data Structure (or contains a Type variable ... does this both mean the same???).

My Problem is now, that I do not know how to pattern match on this.

The Compiler tells me this error:

> ... Problem in this pattern match
>
> The pattern matches things of type:
>
> ```
> ReqRes a
> ```
>
> But the values it will actually be trying to match here are:
>
> ```
> ReqRes
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type variable (`a`) after the `type ... =` or `type alias ... =`, it should appear in the lefthand side too.

Similarly, if there's a type `ReqRes a`, it should always be seen with that `a`.

So, here are changes needed for your code to work:

```
type Msg 
    = NoOp
    | UpdateField ReqRes

... becomes...

type Msg a
    = NoOp
    | UpdateField (ReqRes a)
```

and

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)

... becomes...

update : Msg a -> Model -> (Model, Cmd (Msg a))
```

Comment: Oha, totally right. Thank you. I recognised that this would blow up my whole architecture. Hmm... Plan was to simplify my update function so I have one Messsage that can handle both, Requests and Responses... but there are tons of changes to achieve this in this way, and it does not look like a clean and easy to read enhancement... Maybe I should rely on a lib like remotedata...